# How to import an AAR to Android Studio?

Tags: macos, android-studio, kotlin

There used to be an option to import an external aar under **File > New > New Module > import AAR** but on macOS BigSur, Android Studio Version 4.2.1 this seems to have been removed.

I also tried Import Module but no luck there as well.

Is there an alternative way or am I just missing something?

Comment: I am stuck into same problem. Any work around?

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem. However, it prompts "using project structure".
Open the dialog, and update the app's "Dependencies" instead of "Modules".

Finally, the following result shown in Gradle File:
...
implementation files('drive:\path\mylib.aar')
...